# Cannot ENABLE any API when there is a pending request to DISABLE any API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Yesterday I try to disable "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)" API for two google cloud projects. Unfortunately it seems there was some kind of error as the popup window with something like "Sorry, there was an error on our side" appeared.

An API disapear from list of API but now when I try to enable either "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)" or "Google Cloud Datastore API" (which is v1beta3) I receive following error:

"Cannot ENABLE any API when there is a pending request to DISABLE any API"

Please help, thank you

Comment: Would you be willing to share (email eddavisson@google.com) the project ID you were using when you saw this error? It'd help us ensure this issue doesn't recur.

Comment: @EdDavisson email sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like Google needs to manually solve this for you. I have the same issue, and it being Sunday, it's hard to get support.

Edit: I was directed here https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list

Comment: I just try it and it was possible to enable "Google Cloud Datastore API" so it seems there was something done to fix it on their side as you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug with disabling v1beta2 that causes the operation to hang for a long time.

By design, you can't enable an API when there are other pending enable/disable operations.

We are actively working on the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience!